# Facebook app invite request from website (not canvas) not working - URL not allowed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite

I am trying to send app invite to facebook friends from a website(not from inside facebook app) but am getting this error.

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of 
the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website
URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

The app invite works perfectly from within the facebook app(exactly same code).

These are the settings for my app in facebook:

```
App Domains: ec2-54-200-144-115.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Canvas Url: http://ec2-54-200-144-115.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
Website: http://ec2-54-200-144-115.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/mobile/screen4/
```

The url of page that loads the facebook app invite is the same url given in website section of app settings. Still it is complaining that urls don't match.

Comment: That is because invites is for games that have canvas presence. You can read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: @WizKid Do that mean it can only be used from facebook canvas i.e. from within the facebook app?

Comment: Yes. The link I gave you also say: "If your app has a Canvas presence, you may also use the Requests Dialog on iOS and Android". It doesn't say you can use it on an external website

Comment: @WizKid How can I invite friends to app on external website then? Any suggestions?

Comment: As the link I gave you suggest. Use the send or message dialog. Or alternatively the share dialog